# cant retrieve any cookies with $_COOKIE wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I am trying to retrieve a cookie I set using setcookie(). These are session cookies and set to the root of the domain site.

After much testing the problem has come down to certain server that wordpress is running. It works in my local and even on a hosted development server, but on the production server it can't read the cookies.

Currently the cookie is being set thusly:

```
setcookie("visited", "true", mktime(23,59,59,12,31,2015), "/");
```

I have also tried using

```
setcookie("visited", "true", mktime(23,59,59,12,31,2015), "/", ".mydomain.com");
```

To make it more accessible as what other forums have mentioned.

I used to run this code in the header.php file of setting and getting cookies with php, then moved it to functions.php after finding out wordpress will muck with the header which could screw things up. This still did not fix the problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated?

Comment: Is the Apache `session_cookie_module` enabled on the server?

Comment: Bear in mind that if you set a cookie by PHP you should do it before sending output because cookies are set in headers.

Comment: @mevius - checked it is enabled.

Comment: @SkarXa - have it set to run on the 'init' hook.

Comment: @Anand - currently using $_COOKIE to read it and it works fine on all my other builds of the site, except my live one

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WP Engine, most likely `$_COOKIE` will be an empty array, because of their caching system. An exception to caching, are pages with a cookie containing `wordpress_`.

You can use this loophole by creating a cookie prefixed with `wordpress_` on that page, and voila, `$_COOKIE` will be populated.

JavaScript
`document.cookie = "wordpress_dummy=dummy; max-age=" + 60*60*24*99`

PHP
`setcookie('wordpress_dummy', 'dummy', strtotime('+99 days'));`

By the way, only use this on pages that need them. Otherwise, your site will slow down considerably, because nothing will be cached. Also set cookie expiration responsibly.